# Why is /lib/libc.so.6 missing?

Tags: libraries

```
find | grep libc.so.6
```

reveals that it's in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, but a script I was running expected it to be directly under `/lib`, so why isn't there at least a symlink?

Would I risk breaking anything if I put a symlink there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`libc.so` was moved as part of the [multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) work in Ubuntu 11.04.  The reason that there can't be a symlink there is that the purpose of multiarch is to make it possible to install both the `i386` and `amd64` versions of `libc` at the same time so that you can run 32-bit binaries more easily on 64-bit systems and vice versa (and other similar situations).  If the `libc6` package contained a symlink to the new location, then the versions of that package for different architectures wouldn't both be installable at the same time (which version of the symlink would `dpkg` pick?), defeating the entire point of the exercise.

Anything that hardcodes the path to `libc.so` must be updated to work properly from Ubuntu 11.04 onwards.  If the script you're talking about is part of Ubuntu, please report a bug on it and add the `multiarch` tag.

Comment: Nice answer, learned something new today (again) :)

Comment: The processor I'm using doesn't even support 64 bit instructions. Would you say there's any risk associated with manually adding a symlink? Not sure I need to do that, but if. Anyway, this seems to be the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Erik B: what? Are you telling me you're trying to use a 64 app on a 32 bits processor? That's definitely **not** going to work. 32 bits apps work fine on a 64 bits processor, but not vice versa.

Comment: @Lekensteyn that's definitely not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that I have no use for the 64 bit library. So on my particular system there's not going to be any confusion about whether `/lib/libc.so.6` is the 32 or 64 bit library.

Comment: If you're never going to use 64-bit packages, I doubt there's any significant risk in adding a symlink, no.

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic libraries are loaded by the kernel, the paths are not hardcoded in a program. A program just says "I need libc.so.6". The system then searches in library paths as defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, including `/usr/lib` and `/lib` by default. This file includes additional configuration files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

On my 64 bits system, `libc.so.6` can be found in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` because of the path defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`:

```
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

To find out what library is loaded by a program, use `ldd` as in `ldd /bin/bash`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff1dff000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f9d8b3b8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d8b1b4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d8ae1f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d8b61c000)
```

Putting the symlink would not break anything.

To get a list of directories that are searched, run:

```
ldconfig -v -N | grep '^/'
```

`-v` causes a list of file + directories to be shown, `-N` prevents the cache (`/etc/ld.so.cache`) from being recreated.

Comment: Putting the symlink would not break anything, but it wouldn't really do anything good either, right?

Comment: @Erik B: what program / script are you referring to? I can understand that a script gets confused because the path is hardcoded. But a program does not have to know the path.

Comment: Is that how it works? I seem to have issues sometimes where programs cannot find libraries installed in `/usr/local/lib`, but they work fine if I make a symlink from `/usr/lib`. What causes this behavior?

Comment: @crazy2be: can you post the output of `ldconfig -v -N | grep '^/'` ?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Sure: http://pastebin.com/dtfnw2Tv. It's happened with some programs on almost any system i've used, however, so I assumed it was not related to system configuration.

Comment: @crazy2be: what's `/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14-gdb.py` doing there? Only shared libraries (`*.so`) should be placed there and their symlinks with version information (`*.so.x`, `*.so.x.y` and `*.so.x.y.z`). I think that file is an installer, not actually a shared library.

Answer (score 5):

Just add symlink to the libc.so.6 file as following:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

The same goes for other missing files still on the system, in my case Matlab was missing the file, the problem is gone now.