# Missing /lib/libc.so.6

Tags: installation, dependencies

Software that I'm installing requires `/lib/libc.so.6`, but it's not in place:

```
$> ls -l /lib/libc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 2011-10-09 06:02 /lib/libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18832 2011-02-16 03:42 /lib/libcap.so.2.20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1620736 2012-05-23 07:19 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

`libc` and `libc6-dev` are installed. Running `apt-get upgrade glibc` does not solve this.

What should I do to resolve this dependency?

Comment: Provide output of the following: `ls -l /lib/libc*`

Comment: updated output of this command

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40416/why-is-lib-libc-so-6-missing.

Comment: Try to find it in any directory: `locate libc.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A quick solution.**

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

For 64-bit Ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1):

On my 64-bit Ubuntu it needed to be:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

(i.e. the 64 bit library is below /lib, not /lib64)

Comment: I had the same thing on Xubuntu14.04.1 64bit, so I'm not sure about marking this answer as "not useful" . If x86_64-linux-gnu is under lib/ instead of lib64/ is that not a Xubuntu thing/mistake?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run

```
sudo apt install ia32libs
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.....
Try this command:
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

---